# TikZ: how to make the figure as big as the page

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code for a generating a diagram. How do I make the resulting PDF as large as the figure only like IPE does?

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3 cm,scale=1,transform shape,line width=0.25mm]  
\node[initial,state,fill=green!20,initial text={},line width=0.25mm] (A)    {$q_{000}$};
\node[state,accepting,fill=red!20,line width=0.25mm]         (B) [right of=A]     {$q_{100}$};
\node[state,fill=blue!20,line width=0.25mm]         (C) [right of=B]   {$q_{010}$};
\node[state,accepting,fill=red!20,line width=0.25mm]         (D) [right of=C]   {$q_{110}$};

\node[state,fill=blue!20,line width=0.25mm]   (E) [below of=A]    {$q_{001}$};
\node[state,accepting,fill=red!20,line width=0.25mm]   (F) [right of=E]  {$q_{101}$};
\node[state,fill=blue!20,line width=0.25mm]         (G) [right of=F]     {$q_{011}$};
\node[state,accepting,fill=red!20,line width=0.25mm]    (H) [right of=G]   {$q_{111}$};

\path[->,black] (A) edge [loop above]   node [align=center]  {$ 0$} (A)
(B) edge [above] node [align=center] {$0$} (A)
(C) edge [above] node [align=center] {$0$} (B)
(D) edge [ above, bend right ] node [align=center] {$0$} (B)

(A) edge [ left ] node [align=center] {$1$} (E)
(B) edge [ above ] node [align=center,xshift=-5] {$1$} (E)
(E) edge [ bend left = 6, above ] node [align=center] {$0$} (C)

(C) edge [ bend right = 10, above] node [align=center,xshift=-8,yshift=-5] {$1$} (F)
(F) edge [ bend right = 10, below ] node [align=center,xshift=8,yshift=5] {$0$} (C)

(F) edge [  ] node [align=center] {$1$} (G)
(G) edge [  ] node [align=center] {$1$} (H)
(H) edge [loop right]   node [align=center]  {$ 1$} (H)
(H) edge [ right ] node [align=center] {$0$} (D)
(G) edge [ below ] node [align=center,xshift=5] {$0$} (D)
(D) edge [ bend left = 5,above] node [align=center,yshift=3] {$1$} (F)
(E) edge [ below, bend right  ] node [align=center] {$1$} (G);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Updated working code. Thanks for the help!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3 cm,scale=1,transform shape,line width=0.25mm]  
\node[initial,state,fill=green!20,initial text={},line width=0.25mm] (A)    {$q_{000}$};
\node[state,accepting,fill=red!20,line width=0.25mm]         (B) [right of=A]     {$q_{100}$};
\node[state,fill=blue!20,line width=0.25mm]         (C) [right of=B]   {$q_{010}$};
\node[state,accepting,fill=red!20,line width=0.25mm]         (D) [right of=C]   {$q_{110}$};

\node[state,fill=blue!20,line width=0.25mm]   (E) [below of=A]    {$q_{001}$};
\node[state,accepting,fill=red!20,line width=0.25mm]   (F) [right of=E]  {$q_{101}$};
\node[state,fill=blue!20,line width=0.25mm]         (G) [right of=F]     {$q_{011}$};
\node[state,accepting,fill=red!20,line width=0.25mm]    (H) [right of=G]   {$q_{111}$};

\path[->,black] (A) edge [loop above]   node [align=center]  {$ 0$} (A)
(B) edge [above] node [align=center] {$0$} (A)
(C) edge [above] node [align=center] {$0$} (B)
(D) edge [ above, bend right ] node [align=center] {$0$} (B)

(A) edge [ left ] node [align=center] {$1$} (E)
(B) edge [ above ] node [align=center,xshift=-5] {$1$} (E)
(E) edge [ bend left = 6, above ] node [align=center] {$0$} (C)

(C) edge [ bend right = 10, above] node [align=center,xshift=-8,yshift=-5] {$1$} (F)
(F) edge [ bend right = 10, below ] node [align=center,xshift=8,yshift=5] {$0$} (C)

(F) edge [  ] node [align=center] {$1$} (G)
(G) edge [  ] node [align=center] {$1$} (H)
(H) edge [loop right]   node [align=center]  {$ 1$} (H)
(H) edge [ right ] node [align=center] {$0$} (D)
(G) edge [ below ] node [align=center,xshift=5] {$0$} (D)
(D) edge [ bend left = 5,above] node [align=center,yshift=3] {$1$} (F)
(E) edge [ below, bend right  ] node [align=center] {$1$} (G);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `figure` environment, remove `\usepackage{standalone}` and change to `\documentclass{standalone}`.

#### Unrelated comments.

- Note that while it still works, the `arrows` library is considered deprecated in favor of `arrows.meta`. This does have a different syntax though, see the manual.
- Using the `of=` syntax is deprecated in favor of loading the `positioning` library and saying `=of`, see [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/difference-between-right-of-and-right-of-in-pgf-tikz)
- `\usepackage{tikz}` will also load `pgf` (unsurprisingly) and also `graphicx`, so loading the latter two packages is redundant. You're not using the features of any of the `ams` packages in this figure, so they can be removed as well.
- All the `align=center` doesn't really do anything in this case.
- Personally I would use e.g. `above left` instead of `xshift` and/or `yshift`.
- For cases where you have many elements with the same options, adding a style makes things both neater and easier to change.

#### Complete code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   >={Stealth[round]},shorten >=1pt,
   auto,node distance=2.5cm,
   transform shape,line width=0.25mm,
   StartNode/.style={initial,state,fill=green!20,initial text={},line width=0.25mm},
   TheRedOnes/.style={state,accepting,fill=red!20,line width=0.25mm},
   TheBlueOnes/.style={state,fill=blue!20,line width=0.25mm}
   ]  
\node[StartNode]   (A)                {$q_{000}$};
\node[TheRedOnes]  (B) [right=of A]   {$q_{100}$};
\node[TheBlueOnes] (C) [right=of B]   {$q_{010}$};
\node[TheRedOnes]  (D) [right=of C]   {$q_{110}$};

\node[TheBlueOnes] (E) [below=of A]   {$q_{001}$};
\node[TheRedOnes]  (F) [right=of E]   {$q_{101}$};
\node[TheBlueOnes] (G) [right=of F]   {$q_{011}$};
\node[TheRedOnes]  (H) [right=of G]   {$q_{111}$};

\path[->,black] (A) edge [loop above]  node   {$ 0$} (A)
(B) edge [above] node {$0$} (A)
(C) edge [above] node {$0$} (B)
(D) edge [ above, bend right ] node {$0$} (B)

(A) edge  node  [left] {$1$} (E)
(B) edge node [above left] {$1$} (E)
(E) edge [ bend left = 6 ] node [above] {$0$} (C)

(C) edge [ bend right = 10] node [left=3pt] {$1$} (F)
(F) edge [ bend right = 10] node [right=3pt] {$0$} (C)

(F) edge  node {$1$} (G)
(G) edge  node {$1$} (H)
(H) edge [loop right]   node {$ 1$} (H)
(H) edge  node [ right ] {$0$} (D)
(G) edge  node [below right] {$0$} (D)
(D) edge [ bend left = 5 ] node [above] {$1$} (F)
(E) edge [ bend right ] node [below] {$1$} (G);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can also drop `pgf`, `graphicx` and probably some more as they are loaded anyway.

Comment: @cfr Didn't think about `graphicx`, but good point. Am editing my answer at the moment, so will include that.

Comment: Thank you. Just a had trouble to install it in Ubuntu 15.04. :) Finally succeeded by extracting the ZIP file into texmf directory in the home folder. 

ZIP file URL: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone?lang=en

Comment: @AnirbanGhosh If you have the `standalone` package you should have the `standalone` class as well, they are part of the same bundle.

Comment: @AnirbanGhosh As you can see I added a suggestion for changes to the code in my answer.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. Strangely it is not working in my system. I do not know why. If use standalone in documentclass, compilation fails.